# django custom datetime format not working with form fields

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm working on a Django project where I wanted to add a date format for local usage. As per the documentation, I have updated the settings to use local date time format : [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS)

Settings are as below:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    "%Y-%m-%d",
    "%m/%d/%Y",
    "%m/%d/%y",
    "%b %d %Y",
    "%b %d, %Y",
    "%d %b %Y",
    "%d %b, %Y",
    "%B %d %Y",
    "%B %d, %Y",
    "%d %B %Y",
    "%d %B, %Y",
    '%d-%m-%Y',
    '%d/%m/%Y'
]
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f",
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f",
    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M",
    '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',
    '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
]
```

But for the form fields, it's still using the default date time formats and not taking the date time formats added in the settings file.

In my form, the form throws validation error saying "Enter a valid date/time"

```
class CDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
        model = CDetails
        fields = ('c_date',)
        widgets = {
            'c_date': forms.DateTimeInput(
                attrs={'class': 'datetimepicker-input datetime_stamp form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        }

    def is_valid(self):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        result = super(CDetailsForm, self).is_valid()
        return result
```

DateTimeInput widget code says it refers the **DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS** settings

```
class DateTimeInput(DateTimeBaseInput):
    format_key = 'DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS'
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/datetime.html'
```

But in the form field validation the settings is completely ignored

```
> <project>/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py(384)to_python()
-> for format in self.input_formats:
(Pdb) self.input_formats
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y']
(Pdb) self
<django.forms.fields.DateTimeField object at 0x128049c10>
(Pdb) value
'19-03-2024 17:25:17'
(Pdb)
```

Looking forward to suggestions or feedback.

Comment: This is for *input*, as the name suggests, not how to *render* the item.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem My issue is with the validation. The form rendering has been addressed in the frontend. From the frontend, I have got "19-03-2024 17:25:17". So, when the form is validating shouldn't it validate keeping the global settings? for our case date time input format?